# visiting stores thrice in a a months given the weekoff of the store and annual day holiday

Tags: python, pandas

```
    Hi Guys, I am new to python and in this problem I want the manger to  visit each store assign to him thrice in a month given the weekoff of the stores and Anuual holiday for the month.In the below data "Store" column is the store assign to managers and "Store_visit is the nothing but.
    eg:
    A_1--1st visit
    A_2---2ND visit
    A_3---3rd visit

    1)the constraints for the problem is we cannot make a visit on the weekoff for the corresponding store and on the Anual holiday i.e '10-05-2020'
    2)and the gap between the visit i.e A_1 , A_2 and A_3 should be of 8 days as shown in the output dataframe 'df2'.
    3)we can have a gap of 9 days between the visits only if there is a holiday on the on day of the visit.

    eg:
    in the output dataframe gap between A_2 and A_3 is 9 days because we cannot visit on 10-05-2020 due to holiday.

    start date of the month = 21-04-2020
    end date fo the month =20-05-2020
    "SU" = Sunday
    "T"  =Tuesday
    a)input dataframe == df1
    store   visit store_visit  Manager week0ff_1    weekoff_2  holiday
    A          1    A_1         Rahul       SU           T      10-05-2020
    A          2    A_2         Rahul       SU           T      10-05-2020
    A          3    A_3         Rahul        SU          T      10-05-2020
    B          1    B_1         Rahul        SU                 10-05-2020
    B          2    B_2         Rahul        SU                 10-05-2020
    B          3    B_3         Rahul        SU                 10-05-2020
    C          1    C_1         Raj          SU          T       10-05-2020
    C          2    C_2         Raj          SU          T       10-05-2020
    C          3    C_3         Raj          SU                  10-05-2020
    D          1    D_1         Raj          SU                  10-05-2020
    D          2    D_2         Raj          SU                 10-05-2020
    D          3    D_3          Raj         SU                 10-05-2020

    I am looking for the output mention below..Kindly help me please,couldn't think of logic.

    output dataframe = df2

    Date           Week-day       Rahul    Raj
    21-04-2020  Tuesday            B_1     D_1
    22-04-2020  Wednesday          A_1     C_1
    23-04-2020  Thursday        
    24-04-2020  Friday      
    25-04-2020  Saturday        
    26-04-2020  Sunday      
    27-04-2020  Monday      
    28-04-2020  Tuesday     
    29-04-2020  Wednesday       
    30-04-2020  Thursday           B_2    D_2
    01-05-2020  Friday             A_2    C_2
    02-05-2020  Saturday        
    03-05-2020  Sunday      
    04-05-2020  Monday      
    05-05-2020  Tuesday     
    06-05-2020  Wednesday       
    07-05-2020  Thursday        
    08-05-2020  Friday      
    09-05-2020  Saturday          B_3     D_3
    10-05-2020  Sunday         Holiday  Holiday
    11-05-2020  Monday            A_3      C_3
    12-05-2020  Tuesday     
    13-05-2020  Wednesday       
    14-05-2020  Thursday        
    15-05-2020  Friday      
    16-05-2020  Saturday        
    17-05-2020  Sunday  
    18-05-2020  Monday      
    19-05-2020  Tuesday     
    20-05-2020  Wednesday
```

Comment: [Offset aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)
Flexible sampling is possible on weekdays and holidays. See also.

Comment: thanks..I am looking for solution..can u help me in that

Comment: anyone can help me please

Comment: There is no data in the first 'df1' that is, for example, B_1->21-04-2020,C_1->22-04-2020. So I don't think it can be converted to the desired format.

Comment: first dataframe df1 has folloing columns:   store  , visit ,store_visit,  Manager, week0ff_1    weekoff_2  ,holiday